# Chrome extension, programmatic injection of contentscripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs contentscripts inside IFrames inside the backgroundpage.

Also I don't want to use the `<all_urls>` permission. I want to request only the needed host-permissions at runtime.

I can't find a way to do both.

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are the two ways to declare contentscripts.

The problem with the manifest file is: I can't specify a match-pattern, because I don't know the hosts, and I don't want to use the `<all_urls>` match-pattern. Is there a way to change this setting at runtime?

The problem with the programmatic injection is: The backgroundpage doesn't have a `tabId`. Without it I can't use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Is there another way to inject a contentscript into an IFrame inside the backgroundpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible *yet*. [Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719915) is the feature request I made. They say:

> it's probably not something we can get to immediately